# Any one that can help me with ActionScript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to create a function that allows the user to enter a name via a text field in Flash. Once entered the name should then be checked against a known list of ten names. If the name string is empty the user should be prompted for name. If the name is valid then a message indicating a match was found should be printed and the user should be prompted to see if they wish to enter another name. If neither of these two conditions exists then a message should be printed indicating that the name cannot be found and therefore is not valid and the user should be prompted to enter another name

So far I've got this:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Assignment1 extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Assignment1()
        {
            var names: Array = new Array("David", "Daniel", "Stephanie", "Maria", "Francisco", "Fatima", "Jessica", "Ethan", "Luerdes", "Joaquim");

            var UserName: TextField = new TextField();
            addChild(UserName);

            UserName.text = "David";

            if (UserName in names)
            {
                var found: TextField = new TextField();
                addChild(found);
                found.text = "Match Found";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

please i need help with this question

Thank you in advanced

Comment: [whathaveyoutried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i have this so far(not sure if im doing this correctly):

Comment: package
{
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.text.TextField;
 
 public class Assignment1 extends MovieClip
 {
  
  public function Assignment1()
  {
   var names:Array = new Array("David", "Daniel", "Stephanie", "Maria", "Francisco", "Fatima", "Jessica", "Ethan", "Luerdes", "Joaquim");
   
   var UserName:TextField = new TextField();
   addChild(UserName);
   
   UserName.text = "David";
   
   if (UserName in names)
   {
    var found:TextField= new TextField();
    addChild(found);
    
    found.text = "Match Found";
   }
   
   
   
  
  }
  
 

  
 }
  
  
 
 
}

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that `in` does something that it does not. `in` is used in loops, not to determine whether a value is found in an array.

You can use [`indexOf()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf%28%29) to determine whether a value is found within an array:

```
var inArray:Boolean = names.indexOf( UserName.text ) >= 0;

if(inArray)
{
    // Show your success message here.
    //
}
```

Comment: o i see.. ty... im kinda used to python... also i was wondering, how do i ask for the user's input. 

lets say, how do i ask the user to input a string

Comment: yes, my plan was to ask the user to input a name, and then code will check if that name (String) is in the array

Comment: Im not really sure what your asking me.. sorry

Comment: ok, should i start with label.text = " "?

Comment: o ok, but when i run the code, how would it ask the user to input a string?


Thank you again for the help

Comment: im not sure if im asking that correctly

Comment: yes, but I dont know how to create the line of code in order for them to insert the text. lol

Comment: @DaOu `UserName.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;` Is this what you want?

Comment: yea i think so but how would i input that into my code?

Comment: @DaOu Directly under `var UserName: TextField = new TextField();`

Comment: yea thats what i already have on my code but how do i have the user create its own variable instead of me creating it?

Comment: for example i know when using java , and when i want to ask the user to input a string i have to import java.util.scanner;  and then i have to create it like: (Scanner.scan = new Scanner(System.in)) but im not sure how to do it in actionscript

Comment: @DaOu Yeah so AS is a little different. You don't need to create an input stream or anything like that, you just have the textbox there and you can at any time get the value that the user has written in there via `.text`.

Comment: o ok, thanks alot. I appreciate all of your help

Comment: so would i do this:

UserName.text= TextFieldType.INPUT;

Comment: @DaOu No, `UserName.type = `.